# What is wrong with this simple v-if?

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to understand Vue. I am following `vuejs.org`

I am trying to make the below code work. But I am failing somewhere.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/3x18v6kg/9/)

I have the below code.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  "el":"#app1",
  "data":{
    showme:true
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div v-if="showme" id="app1">
  <div id="app2">
    IF is true
  </div>
</div>

 <div v-else id="app3">
  Else is happening
</div>
```

Comment: id="app3" is outside id="app1", https://jsfiddle.net/dm7osrj9/1/

Comment: @LawrenceCherone You deserve the approve vote. If you would like to add an answer, I will do it.

Comment: Na is ok, is just a typo imo, glad it helped

Comment: You need one "top level" <div id="app"> to attach your vue instance.You shouldn't add any vue logic to that div. **v-if** should be added to child div's. Also, **v-else** should match nesting level of **v-if**. In your example, **v-if** and **v-else** are not sibling elements and that's why your **v-else** fails

Comment: Thanks @ijubdar. I just figured out. I thought I can continuously give different elements sequentially so if-elseIf-else ll be handled properly. I missed the main vue instance part.

Comment: No problem. I know vueJs  can be a bit overwhelming at the beginning. VueJs has an amazing documentation and I recommend you to keep the docs open at all times and to use the search functionality at the top. For example, when you search **v-if** you will get results in different sections: **API**, **Guide**, ... - use the results from **Guide** section while you learn, but look into API as well :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Vue app attaches itself to a single DOM element (#app1 in our case) then fully controls it. The HTML is our entry point, but everything else happens within the newly created Vue instance.

```
<div id="app1">
 <div v-if="showme">
  <div id="app2">
   IF is true
  </div>
 </div>

 <div v-else id="app3">
  Else is happening
 </div>
</div>

var vm = new Vue({
"el":"#app1",
"data":{
 showme:false
}
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Plus1. Could you add that in words also? Because in [this](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) page, it is kind of sequential elements. I am completely missing the basics. Your words will help others too.